# create trigger for IF condition in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created a trigger which inserts City as `Others` for all the data inserted with City name `OTHERS`

But it updates as `null` for text other than `OTHERS`. So I want to add `IF` condition for the same. Below is my trigger.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TGR_UPD_OTHERS_TVIPL
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON IPCOLO_IPFEE_CALC_MST
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     new.CITY := case :NEW.CITY
                     when 'OTHERS' THEN 'Others'
                     end;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you didn't say what to do "else":

```
:new.city := case when :new.city = 'OTHERS' then 'Others'
                  else :new.city
             end;
```

Comment: In front end; it is responsible for displaying values. Somewhere is *something* set to display 0 as "undefined". Could even be in front end's query (using CASE or DECODE).

Comment: Should work for any table (unless there's something that prevents it to; perhaps another trigger?).

Comment: If you can afford dropping it, do it and you'll see whether there's any difference. On the other hand, did you debug it first? I mean, maybe there's some (not that) obvious reason which prevents trigger from working.

Comment: I cant see any reason for the same. yes i can afford deleting the table as its on dev env.

Comment: What is "it"? Select statement you ran in e.g. SQL Developer, or your front-end application?

Comment: No, as DECODE requires (at least) the 3rd parameter - what to display if that column's value is equal to 0. It appears that - if the result is "undefined" - query looks like `select decode(mw_antenna_of_upto06_dia, 0, 'undefined') from ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245704/discussion-between-nad-and-littlefoot).